# Apache HTTP Client Server TLS Implementation:getting Keystore Exceptions

Tags: java, apache, https, apache-httpclient-4.x

**SERVER SIDE:**

1. I have secure RESTful service deployed on Tomcat for which the HTTPS protocol is enabled.
2. I have created a Keystore serverkeystore file using the `keytool.`
3. Exported the servercertificate.cer from serverkeystore.

**CLIENT SIDE:**

1. Created a Client Keystore clientkeystore.jsk
2. Imported the servercertificate.cer in clientkeystore.jsk
3. Exported the clientcertificate.cer from clientkeystore.jsk.
4. Imported the clientcertificate.cer under JAVA_HOME/lib/security

**Exception in CLIENT SIDE CODE:**

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
... 30 more
```

Code:

```
private SSLConnectionSocketFactory buildSSLSocketFactory() throws Exception, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
    KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File("path to clientkeystore.jks"));
    try {
        trustStore.load(instream, "phhclient".toCharArray());
    } finally {
        instream.close();
    }
    // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();
    // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslcontext,
            new String[] { "TLSv1" },
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);


    return sslsf;
}
```

unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Please Let me know Why I am getting the exception

Thanks and Regards,

Rahul Jain

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this exception is code is unable to find server certificate in the client's trust store. Kindly check whether the server certificate is added to your client truststore. Also, TrustManagerFactory is not instantiated in the function.

Following code can be used for building SSL Socket Factory. Kindly include necessary import statement :

```
SSLSocketFactory buildSSLSocketFactory() throws Exception {
    SSLContext sslcontext = null;

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    KeyStore trustks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    File trustcert = new File("path to truststore");
    InputStream truststream = new FileInputStream(trustcert);
    trustks.load(truststream, "password".toCharArray());
    truststream.close();
    tmf.init(trustks);

    try {
        sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sslcontext.init(new KeyManager[0],
                 tmf.getTrustManagers() ,
                new SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {  
        System.out.println("Exception  :"+e);       
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception  :"+e);   
    }

    SSLSocketFactory factory = sslcontext.getSocketFactory();

    return factory; 
}
```